# How to generate pdf report through Maven using FORTIFY's fpr file

Tags: java, maven, fortify, reportgenerator

Hi I am trying to generate a PDF report from fpr file using maven.
Can any one tell me if there is any plugin available for that?

The following is the output that i want to achieve but from maven.
Command in command prompt: "ReportGenerator -format pdf -f outputFile.pdf -source dev-rkm-KMS-aggregate.fpr "

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exec plugin to run the reportgenerator:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
       <goals>
         <goal>exec</goal>
       </goals>
       <phase>...</phase>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>ReportGenerator</executable>
      <!--optional -->
      <arguments>
        <argument>...</argument>   
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```